# React setState with []

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, syntax, setstate

Everyone, I have a question about some syntax I saw.

```
state = {
    nom : '',
    image : '',
    ingredients : '',
    instructions : ''
}


handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    console.log(name)
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
}

...
<div className="card">
    <form action="" className="admin-form ajouter-recette">
        <input value={this.state.nom} onChange={this.handleChange} type='text' name="nom" placeholder="Nom de la recettte"/> 
        <input value={this.state.image} onChange={this.handleChange} type='text' name="image" placeholder="image"/>
        <textarea value={this.state.ingredients} onChange={this.handleChange} name="ingredients" rows='3' placeholder="liste des ingredients"></textarea>
        <textarea value={this.state.instructions} onChange={this.handleChange} name="instructions" rows='15' placeholder="liste des instructions"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

Basically, the `handleChange` is done to set a state, regarding the event name and value, which is different from all the inputs and textarea to avoid having for `handleChange` functions.

By destructuring, we retrieve `{ name, value }`.

Then to set the state, it is done like this

```
this.setState({ [name]: value })
```

I don't understand why the `[ ]` are needed to wrap the name property, because without it seems not to be working.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's called a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use ES6 computed property syntax for object setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55713110/why-use-es6-computed-property-syntax-for-object-setstate)

Answer (score 2):

If you ever want to set/get a JavaScript object's key from a variable then the `objectName[variableName]` syntax is used.

In the example that you have shared, the name and value are being fetched

```
const {name, value} = event.target
```

The name property from the DOM nodes matches the key defined in the state
So now I have the value of the property in my name variable. So for the specific case of 'nom', the `name` variable has a value nom. So now the statement

```
this.setState({[name]: value})
```

will evaluate to

```
this.setState({nom: value})
```

More info at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score -1):

Those are called property accessors. In your case the name of the field is used as the accessor, hence we add [] to tell javascript that you are using an accessor, if not all your values will be assigned to `name` property of your state.

More info can be found here: [Mozille docs - Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: The syntax is related to property accessors, but it is not a property accessor.